# How to mock datetime.now() using pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-mock

I'm working on a Python project and I want to mock a variable that uses datetime.now(). Is it possible to achieve this without using libraries like "freeze_time"??
app.py:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta

def foo():
    now = datetime.now()
    
    return now - timedelta(days=15)
```

I've tried using mocker.patch("app.datetime.now", return_value=date(2011, 11, 18)), but I suspect this is the wrong way to patch it. What should I do?

Comment: Use the freezer plugin [pytest-freezer](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-freezer).

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/freezegun/